# how to join two tables to update the value for one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables with thousand of records for students doing activities every year:

`table1`

```
year | Id | Activity | Name
2001   1       a       Mike
2001   1       b       Mike
2002   1       c       Mike
2003   1       c       Mike
```

`table2`

```
Year | Id | Grade
2001   1     7
2002   1     8
2003   1     9
```

I want to get the query in below format,

I still could not figure it out. Please help

```
year | Id | Activity | Name | Grade |
2001   1       a       Mike     7        
2001   1       b       Mike     7       
2002   1       c       Mike     8       
2003   1       c       Mike     9
```

Here is what I wrote

```
Select t1.year,t1.Id,t1.Activity,t1.Name,t2.Grade
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.year=t1.year AND t2.Id=t1.Id
```

Comment: do you have any query that you wrote

Comment: which column you want to update ?

Comment: the grade column need to be updated when year is changed

Answer (score 1):

```
Select t1.year,t1.Id,t1.Activity,t1.Name,t2.Grade
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.year=t1.year AND t2.Id=t1.Id
```

Answer (score -1):

Use JOIN: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/07/19/671712.aspx
And UPDATE statement: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx

Hope this helps!